# How to back up MySQL table into a dump with PHP?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Is there any way to dump whole database using php **but not to CSV or XML** because I need it in pure SQL format.

Example of dump I need:

```
CREATE TABLE 'table_name' etc..;
INSERT INTO 'table_name' (field, field2) VALUES ('1','2');
INSERT INTO 'table_name' (field, field2) VALUES ('1','2');
```

I don't have usage of **exec()** or **system().**
And without manually creating an INSERT statement.. 
Example:

```
while($row = mysql_results) {
 $sql_dump = 'INSERT INTO ...';
}
```

Thank you! :)

Comment: See this question of mine. You are off topic here.

http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/24260/how-can-i-automate-retrieval-of-mysql-databases-from-shared-hosting-which-disall/24409#24409

Comment: If you can't run `exec` or `system` and you have critical data to backup I have to ask why you're hosting this critical data on what is probably a shared server (or at least one you don't have full access to)? You might try [PHPMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/) if you're not terribly well-versed in this area. It makes dumping sql files simple.

Comment: why not use `mysqldump`?

Comment: @xdazz: I understand the original poster's pain. If he is on a shared hosting with no ssh access and no exec, he is stuck. I am/was in the same situation, see link above.

Comment: Really, why not use phpMyAdmin? Otherwise, you're stuck with SHOW TABLES, SHOW CREATE TABLE and manually writing INSERTs, yep. (what's so hard about it?)

Comment: Even if you don't want to use phpmyadmin - you can get the code it runs to produce such a dump

Answer (score 2):

You can run a SHOW CREATE TABLE  query. This is done from within a mysql client:

```
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table | Create Table                                                   |
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| test2 | CREATE TABLE `test2` (
  `AAA` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Data of course can be retrieved through any regular select statement and if you're doing it with a scripting language you can then store the data however you need.

If you're simply in the mysql client and have access to the file system you can run a Select ... Into Outfile statement:

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'backup.tab'
ENCLOSED BY '"'
FROM <TableName>;
```

The above will create a tab separated file.

To load the data back in run:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'backup.tab'
INTO TABLE <TableName>
ENCLOSED BY '"';
```

Trying to recreate INSERT statements from within MySQL will likely end up with issues over escaping special characters and things like that. Using CSV or Tab separated data files is seen as perfectly standard for exporting and importing data.

Comment: That is for the table structure, but not for actual data :(

Comment: Well the data you can retrieve through any regular select statement. If you have access to the file system your mysql client is running on you can do a Select ... Into Outfile. I will edit my answer to show this.

Comment: @llion have you actually read my post? ... if you have then you should be able to notice that I mentioned I want an SQL dump, not tabbed output etc... I want dump which consists of this:

CREATE TABLE bla
INSERT INTO bla (bla) VALUES (bla)
INSERT INTO bla (bla) VALUES (bla)
INSERT INTO bla (bla) VALUES (bla)
etc...

So your solution is not fine for me

Comment: Yes I have. The only way to get that is to use mysqldump, which I'm pretty sure is what phpMyAdmin plugs into as well. Since you used a MySQLDump tag (unless it was edited in) it seemed you knew about this utility and needed an option. These are your other options.

Answer (score 0):

If you have remote access to database (MySQL port not ssh) you can try to set up synchronization between servers. You can use some other server where you have open or required access. a setup on localhost is enough.
Recent versions of PHPMyAdmin provides a functionality to set synchronization (install it on your local machine). Also SQLYog supports sync functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
$command="mysqldump  --host=localhost --user=USER --password=***** DATABASENAME.table > db.sql";
system($command);
```